# VS 2010 Javascript Matching Brace/Bracket Highlighting

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2013

Recently I upgraded to Visual Studio 2010 in the hope that it would provide matching bracket hightlighting for Javascript as it does for C#.

On the project I am working on I am doing more Javascript than C# and I finding the lack of bracket matching quite painful.

Is there any method of turning on this feature for Javascript too?

EDIT December 2015: Right now I am using Viasfora extension which does rainbow braces like vim, emacs. Each bracket pair has is successively given a different color, so you dont have to put the caret next to a bracket. Using it in vs 2013.

Answer (score 11):

Microsoft has released [JScript Editor Extensions](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/872d27ee-38c7-4a97-98dc-0d8a431cc2ed) for this. It also has support for intellisense comments. This works great when referencing in th jQuery vsdoc.

[image: Screenshot]

Answer (score 8):

[JSEnhancements](http://visualstudiogallery.msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/0696ad60-1c68-4b2a-9646-4b5f4f8f2e06)

> This extension provides outlining and
>   matching braces highlighting features
>   for Visual Studio JavaScript and CSS
>   editor.
>
> Works both in JS/CSS files and HTML
>   script/style blocks.
>
> Outlining is like in C# editor. It
>   outlines {}'s, []'s and #region tags

[image]

Comment: Thank you a lot for this! It will save me a lot of time I am sure.